# Sorting JSON with values from database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the below situation

I have a database table as below

```
user_id user_rank
------------------
22       10
32        9
43        7
31        6
```

and i have a JSON Object with the user id like (other nodes in json are hidden for simplicity, consider this response is from an api)

```
{"user_id":[31,22,43,32]}
```

now, how do i sort the JSON result based on the rank of a user_id in database and produce a
result like

```
{"user_id":[22,32,43,31]}
```

is there anything like LINQ in rails, so that i can save the json object values in it,
and make join between the object and database table to obtain the sorted json?

Comment: I am searching for LINQ like stuff with Rails.. so that i can copy values from JSON to the object and then make a join between the object and database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have user ids in json then :

```
require 'json'
user_hash = JSON.parse('{"user_id":[31,22,43,32]}') => {"user_id"=>[31, 22, 43, 32]}

users = User.all(:conditions=>["id in ?",user_hash[:user_id]])
sort_user_id = users.sort { |x, y| (x.user_rank|| 0 )<=> (y.user_rank|| 0)}.map(&:id)
{:user_id => sort_user_id}.to_json
```

Hope that help.